# Creating a line graph based on user input points

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graph, jframe

I have a homework assignment where I must make a program that asks the user for 4 points, and calculates the slope/equation of the line. I want to, once the user hits the calculate button to display a simple line graph graph in the left corner of the window of my program.

How should I go about doing this?  It just needs to plot the y intercept and show the line and I just don't know how to really tackle this. I have the program running fine and everything works great just need to get started on the graph and I don't know how to get started. Any ideas?

If you copy paste my code into JGrasp or whatever IDE you will see what I mean, I just want to add a graph into the mix.

How should I make a graph, and how should I go about putting it in the window so that it changes when I hit calculate?

Here is my code:

```
public class lineCalculator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public lineCalculator() {
initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField9 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); 
    jLabel1.setText("Line Calculator");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel2.setText("X1");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel3.setText("X2");

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel4.setText("Y1");

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel5.setText("Y2");

    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel6.setText("Slope");

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel7.setText("Distance between points");

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jButton1.setText("Calculate");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel8.setText("Angle(radians)");

    jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel9.setText("Angle(degrees)");

    jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel10.setText("Equation of the line");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(211, 211, 211)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 82, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                            .addComponent(jLabel10)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 221, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(141, 141, 141)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 78, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jTextField4))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 86, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 509, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel10)
                .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(49, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}


public boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
try
{
Double.parseDouble(str);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
return (false);
}
return(true);
}

public double Round(double val, int plc)
{
 double pwr = Math.pow(10,plc);
 val = val * pwr;
 double tmp = (int) val;

if( ((int)(val + .5)) == (int) val)
return (tmp/pwr);
else
return((tmp + 1.0)/pwr);
}


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
double x1;
double x2;
double y1;
double y2;
double length_of_x;
double length_of_y;
double slope;
double opposite;

double angle_degrees;
double angle_radians;
double y_intercept;
double distance_between_2_points;

x1 = (double) (Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText()));
x2 = (double) (Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText()));
y1 = (double) (Double.parseDouble(jTextField4.getText()));
y2 = (double) (Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText()));

length_of_x = x2 - x1;
length_of_y = y2 - y1;
slope = length_of_y / length_of_x;
slope = (double) Round(slope,2);
opposite = y2 - y1;
distance_between_2_points = Math.sqrt((length_of_x * length_of_x) + (length_of_y * length_of_y));
distance_between_2_points = (double) Round(distance_between_2_points,2);
angle_radians = opposite / distance_between_2_points;
angle_radians = (double) Round(angle_radians,2);
angle_degrees = angle_radians * (180 / 3.14159);
angle_degrees = (double) Round(angle_degrees,2);
y_intercept = (y1)-(angle_radians * x1);

jTextField5.setText(slope + "");
jTextField6.setText(distance_between_2_points + "");
jTextField7.setText(angle_radians + "");
jTextField8.setText(angle_degrees + "");
jTextField9.setText("Y = " + slope + "" + "X + " + y_intercept + "");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
  for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
      javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
      break;
    }
  }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(lineCalculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(lineCalculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(lineCalculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(lineCalculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

/* Create and display the form */
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    new lineCalculator().setVisible(true);
  }
});
}

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField9;
}
```

Comment: Huh.  `P1` (2,2), `P2` (8,8) -> `Y = 1.0X + 0.5800000000000001`.  Neat.  OK so.. what is your question?  I can think it might be 'Where to put the graph?' or 'How to draw the graph?' or.. but I'm not you and only you know what the question is.  What is your question?

Comment: woops forgot to round y intercept. and the question is how should I make a graph, and how should I go about putting it in a window so that it changes when i hit calculate

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you're going to need to "normalize" the points so that you can make them fit into a known range (as you graph is likely to be a fixed/known size).

This means that the user is not restricted to entering values that fit you graph, they are free to enter what ever values they want.

This basically means you're going to scale the points...something like...

```
// Size of the component
int width = getWidth();
int height = getHeight();

// p1 and p1 two are java.awt.Point references
// The maximum extend of the points
int maxX = Math.max(p1.x, p2.x);
int maxY = Math.max(p1.y, p2.y);

// Generate a "scale to fit"
float scale = Math.min(width / (float)maxX, height / (float)maxY);

// Scale the points..
int x1 = (int)(p1.x * scale);
int y1 = (int)(p1.y * scale);

int x2 = (int)(p2.x * scale);
int y2 = (int)(p2.y * scale);
```

Here's a relatively simple example that generates random points

```
public class TestGraph {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGraph();
    }

    public TestGraph() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new GraphPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GraphPane extends JPanel    {

        private Point p1;
        private Point p2;

        public GraphPane() {

            // Generate random points, replace with your own coordinates
            p1 = getRandomPoint();
            p2 = getRandomPoint();

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            int maxX = Math.max(p1.x, p2.x);
            int maxY = Math.max(p1.y, p2.y);

            float scale = Math.min(width / (float)maxX, height / (float)maxY);

            int x1 = (int)(p1.x * scale);
            int y1 = (int)(p1.y * scale);

            int x2 = (int)(p2.x * scale);
            int y2 = (int)(p2.y * scale);

            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        }

        protected Point getRandomPoint() {
            return new Point(getRandomValue(), getRandomValue());
        }

        protected int getRandomValue() {
            return (int)Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Might like to have a read through

- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

For more information and ideas

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new class that extends JPanel. Then add that JPanel to your existing Frame to your group layout.
In the JPanel you just overwrite the paintComponent(Graphics) method and do the drawing in there.

This is just a quick example using a fixed screen of 400x400 pixels, with 1 pixel equaling 1 coordinate.

You probably want to do some normalization of the displayed screen, where the screen is zoomed in or out depending on the line. I would suggest that you always draw the origin of the coordinate system (0|0) in the middle and just zoom as needed.

```
private class Graph extends JPanel {
    final int screenWidth = 400;
    final int screenHeight = screenWidth;

    final int xAxisPos = screenHeight/2;
    final int yAxisPos = screenWidth/2;

    public Graph() {
        this.setBounds(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    }

    private double y(double x) {
        return 2*x; // This is an example for y=2x
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(0, xAxisPos, screenWidth, xAxisPos); // draws the x-axis
        g.drawLine(yAxisPos, 0, yAxisPos, screenHeight); // draws the y-axis

        int yValueStart = (int) y(-yAxisPos); // calculates the y value on the left edge of the screen
        int yValueEnd = (int) y(screenWidth-yAxisPos); // calculates the y value on the right edge of the screen

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawLine(0, -yValueStart, screenWidth, -yValueEnd);       
    }
}
```

In the above example, I've put the result of your calculation in a function y(double) which return the double value of a certain x value. Also note that when drawing in Swing the coordinate system is flipped, that's why in the drawLine function you have to make the y values negative.

Comment: this makes sense, but explain how i would call the graph() class and put it where it needs to go, for me it just opens in a new window.

Answer (score 2):

> ..how should I go about putting it in the window..?

[image: LineCalculator]

Change the code just prior to `layout.setHorizontalGroup(..` to something like:

```
JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel graphPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JPanel controls = new JPanel();
GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(controls);
controls.setLayout(layout);

gui.add(graphPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(
    200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
graphPanel.add(l);

gui.add(controls);
getContentPane().add(gui);

layout.setHorizontalGroup(..
```

> ..How should I make a graph..?

Draw it to the `BufferedImage`, then `repaint()` the label that displays it.

Comment: what do you mean exactly, draw it ot the bufferedimage. life if i wanted to draw the rectangle that will have the graph inside it would i do like img.repaint() something? im not familiar with bufferedimage

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an object in the awt package and use their method called paint.

You have to then override the method thats is inherited by each component... This is the method

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g);
  g.drawLine(25, 0, 25, 50);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
}
```

After you do this then you have to create the line using the graphics class

The problem with your code is that you are using swing components which are lightweight and prepackaged components I personally wouldnt use them to paint custom items.

Here are some sources:

to get you started: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

a working sample: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawline.htm

Comment: You should, where possible, avoid overriding `paint` and/or painting directly to top level containers.  Instead use something like `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method