# Creating Graph using Swing Graphics

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create line graph using the following code

`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class NewG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                LineComponent lineComponent = new LineComponent(300,300);
                List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
                values.add(100);
                values.add(200);
                values.add(300);
                values.add(400);
                values.add(100);
                values.add(900);
                for (int i=0; i<values.size()-1; i++) {
                    lineComponent.addLine(i+1, values.get(i), i+2, values.get(i+1));
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lineComponent);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class LineComponent extends JComponent {

    ArrayList<Line2D.Double> lines;
    Random random;

    LineComponent(int width, int height) {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        lines = new ArrayList<Line2D.Double>();
        random = new Random();
    }

    public void addLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        lines.add(line);
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        Dimension d = getPreferredSize();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        for (Line2D.Double line : lines) {
            g.drawLine(
                (int)line.getX1(),
                (int)line.getY1(),
                (int)line.getX2(),
                (int)line.getY2()
                );
        }
    }
}
```

`

The output currently is unscaled

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR9Uk.png)

I want to draw the lines in such a way that it represents line graph having points such as

```
(1, 100);
(2, 200);
(3, 300);
(4, 400);
(5, 100);
(6, 900);
```

I am drawing the lines from first point to second then second point to third. However is there any way to scale the graph to be visible properly

Comment: You want to "normalise" the data in some way - that is, the min value is 0, the maximum value is 1 and everything else in between is a fraction of these two - then, based on the height the component, you can calculate the y representation of the graph and the number of elements would be divided by the width

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575142/creating-a-line-graph-based-on-user-input-points/13575574#13575574); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535832/how-to-draw-a-simple-gui-histogram/12538636#12538636)